# Return from @tornado.gen.engine function without yield?

Tags: python, tornado

I'd like to execute or not execute an async query based on the value of a parameter. If the parameter is True, the query shouldn't be executed.

I have a method like this:

```
@tornado.gen.engine
def retrieveSomeData(self, feelingLucky, callback):
    if feelingLucky:
        return      # <-- doesn't work, function never returns!
    else:
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(queryFunction, param1....)
        callback(response)
```

How can I make the `feelingLucky` branch work?

The only thing I can think of is raising an exception and catching it in the caller. But that's very ugly. Or, if there was such a thing as a *null* task...

(Python 2.7, Tornado 3.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use the modern `gen.coroutine` instead of the obsolete `gen.engine`. That makes this sort of conditional logic simple and natural:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def retrieveSomeData(self, feelingLucky):
    if feelingLucky:
        return
    else:
        response = yield Tornado.gen.Task(queryFunction, param1....)
        raise gen.Return(response)
```

If you convert queryFunction to coroutine style too, you get:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def retrieveSomeData(self, feelingLucky):
    if feelingLucky:
        return
    else:
        response = yield queryFunction(param1....)
        raise gen.Return(response)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know you can mix coroutines and engine/tasks. `return` still doesn't work, but now I can do `raise gen.Return()` on the non-yielding branch, so that looks good!

Comment: "return" with no argument is the same as "raise gen.Return()". There may be some confusion about Python 2 and 3: in Python 2 a generator can't return a value, but a bare "return" works the same in Python 2 and 3. Can you say more about what you mean, "return still doesn't work"?

Comment: I'm not sure - it doesn't resume execution where it should and the function/generator never terminates (never returns to the calling code). It's hard to debug because all I can see is the execution looping through gen.py.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
def _nullTask(self, callback):
    callback()

@tornado.gen.engine
def retrieveSomeData(self, feelingLucky, callback):
    if feelingLucky:
        yield tornado.gen.Task(self._nullTask)
        callback(None)
    else:
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(queryFunction, param1....)
        callback(response)
```

Perhaps there is a better way?...

(Based on this comment in `gen.py`:

> For functions that do not return `Futures`, `Task` works with any
>   function that takes a `callback` keyword argument.)